# Quick query for large groups in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I'd like to identify a more efficient method for identifying large AD groups with Powershell (say, more than 5000 users). Listing the members is not required, since I want to **exclude** these groups from another process.

Obviously I can use `Get-ADGroup` as below, but if there's a more efficient way (e.g. by using LDAP filters, etc), that'd be helpful.

```
(Get-ADGroup "Group" -Properties members).members.count | where {$_ -lt 5000}
```

I'm querying members of hundreds of thousands of groups for the actual purpose, and I would like to exclude larger groups in the initial runs (since the main process becomes quite memory intensive on a large group).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer. But you're asking the DC to tell you every member name no matter what. This would take ages. The parentheses around get-adgroup demands every member to be queried and saved in local ram. Then you're telling it to get the method of members. So it relists it. Then get the count.

Maybe if you did this. It would run it in parallel instead of repeating things 2 times. Thus this might save 20-30% of your time.

```
 Get-ADGroup "Group" -Properties members | select -ExpandProperty members | measure | where count -lt 5000
```

here's a sample script to do this automatically... (I changed the ldap filter)

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * | select -expand name | foreach { 
    $group = $_
    if (Get-ADGroup {name -eq $group} -Properties members | select -ExpandProperty members | measure | where count -lt 5000){
        $countedGroups += $group
    }
    $countedGroups
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that syntax doesn't run for me - I think it's counting a "Members" attribute, not the actual members. In other words, the count is always 1, no matter how many members the group has. In any case, the blunt-force method worked sufficiently well after a few hours.

Comment: Sorry, i have corrected my code, it expands the properties so you get a true count. Normaly the members field is contained in a child object. Sorry about that. i didn't have access to AD at the time i wrote this.

Comment: Returning to this very late, I couldn't see any value in inserting a `measure` command when I was already returning the members Count value with my original shorter syntax. Or doing all the property expansions.
It might have been confusing that I didn't show my base filter to get groups that actually had members. It was `Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(member=*)' -properties members ... `